# How do you put an integer array into a setIntValue in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have:

`myAnswerArray[i]` with four-digit integers stored in them like,

```
myAnswerArray[0]=1412
myAnswerArray[1]=0518
myAnswerArray[2]=2307
```

I have an IBOutlet 'answerField'

so I want to `[answerField setIntValue:(something)]`

and have it send:

`1412 0518 2307` to the text field.

Comment: Is the answerField a UITextField?

Comment: I had it as an NSTextField, but not sure what would be best.

Comment: I hope you know that 0518 is not the same as 518. Don't use a leading 0 for alignment reasons. But the compiler should throw an error because of the 8 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small array:

```
[answerField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04i %04i %04i", myAnswerArray[0], myAnswerArray[1], myAnswerArray[2]]];
```

For larger array, build your string using NSMutableString:

```
NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:500];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    [temp appendFormat:@"%04i ", myAnswerArray[i]];
}

[answerField setStringValue:temp];
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
[answerField setStringValue:[myAnswerArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
```

Comment: That won't set the integers to 4 digits if any values are less than 1,000

Comment: I'm getting this warning when I do that, warning: Semantic Issue: Receiver type 'int *' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'

Comment: fyi, this was a simple array that I defined using:  int myAnswerArray[100];

Comment: yeah, I thought it was a NSMutableArray/NSArray.